# Multiple texture units GLES 2.0 Android

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

Trying to get 2 texture units working.

```
@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    //Clear the Rendering Surface
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    multiplyMM(viewProjectionMatrix, 0, projectionMatrix, 0, viewMatrix, 0);

    positionTableInScene();
    textureProgram.useProgram();
    textureProgram.setUniforms(modelViewProjectionMatrix, texture_b, texture_r);
    table.bindData(textureProgram);
    table.draw();
    ...
}
```

Texture Program:

```
public class TextureShaderProgram extends ShaderProgram {
//Uniform locations
private final int uMatrixLocation;
private final int uTextureUnit0Location;
private final int uTextureUnit1Location;

//Attribute locations
private final int aPositionLocation;
private final int aTextureCoordinatesLocation;

public TextureShaderProgram(Context context){
    super(context, R.raw.texture_vertex_shader, R.raw.texture_fragment_shader);

    //Retrieve uniform locations for the shader program.
    uMatrixLocation = glGetUniformLocation(program, U_MATRIX);
    uTextureUnit0Location = glGetUniformLocation(program, U_TEXTURE_UNIT_0);
    uTextureUnit1Location = glGetUniformLocation(program, U_TEXTURE_UNIT_1);

    //Retrieve attribute locations for the shader program.
    aPositionLocation = glGetAttribLocation(program, A_POSITION);
    aTextureCoordinatesLocation = glGetAttribLocation(program, A_TEXTURE_COORDINATES);
}
public void setUniforms(float[] matrix, int textureId, int textureId2){
    //Pass the matrix into the shader program
    glUniformMatrix4fv(uMatrixLocation, 1, false, matrix, 0);

    //Set the active texture unit to texture unit 0.
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    //Bind the texture to this unit.
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);
    //Tell the texture uniform sample to use this texture in the shader by
    //telling it to read from texture unit 0.
    glUniform1f(uTextureUnit0Location, 0);

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId2);
    glUniform1f(uTextureUnit1Location, 0);


}


public int getPositionAttributeLocation(){
    return aPositionLocation;
}

public int getTextureCoordinatesAttributeLocation(){
    return aTextureCoordinatesLocation;
}
}
```

Fragment Shader:

```
precision mediump float;

uniform sampler2D u_TextureUnit0;
uniform sampler2D u_TextureUnit1;
varying vec2 v_TextureCoordinates;

void main()
{

   //gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_TextureUnit0, v_TextureCoordinates);

   gl_FragColor = (v_TextureCoordinates.y > 0.5)
   ?texture2D(u_TextureUnit1, v_TextureCoordinates)
   :texture2D(u_TextureUnit0, v_TextureCoordinates);

}
```

This did not provide me with the desired outcome of half of one texture and half another. i found out this was because my texture units held the same image. Always the image loaded into texture unit 0. changing which texture is loaded first changes the texture so I know both texture work.

I think its the way im informing opengl of where my texture units are. But im not sure how to change it.

Answer (score 5):

Two problems. First of all, you're setting both uniform variables to the same value:

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);
glUniform1f(uTextureUnit0Location, 0);

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId2);
glUniform1f(uTextureUnit1Location, 0);
```

The value you're setting for the uniform variable must match the index of the texture unit the corresponding texture is bound to. Since the second texture is bound to `GL_TEXTURE1`, the second uniform value must be 1, not 0.

Also, uniform values for samplers must be set with `glUniform1i()`, not `glUniform1f()`.

So the correct code looks like this:

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);
glUniform1i(uTextureUnit0Location, 0);

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId2);
glUniform1i(uTextureUnit1Location, 1);
```